# Open an external app using electron with angular

Tags: angular, electron

I am new to electron so I followed the electron docs and try to implement the setup. I have managed to open and build the app since it's the easiest but my main motive is to store some data like we do in localstorage and open those files in photoshop.

Attaching a github repo link of my project for your ref:
https://github.com/futurbotconsolidated/electron

I have tried angular-electron(old and archived) and ngx-electronify(not much support available).

While try to open external app i try to use this:

In main.js file

```
app.on('ready', () => {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
    mainWindow.loadFile('index.html');

    // Example: Listen for an IPC message from the renderer process
    ipcMain.on('callMainFunction', (event, args) => {
        myFunctionInMainProcess();
    });
});
```

In app.component.ts

```
callMainFunction() {
        // Example: Send an IPC message to call the function in the main process
        ipcRenderer.send('callMainFunction', { /* additional data if needed */ });
    }
```

If anyone could guide me through the process of setting this in angular and how to use shell operations and If you have any demo project you could share it would be of much help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In main.js inside ipcMain.on
you can run this function

```
function run_script(command, args, callback) {
      var child = child_process.spawn(command, args, {
        encoding: 'utf8',
        shell: true,
      });

      child.on('error', (error) => {
        // dialog.showMessageBox({
        //   title: 'Title',
        //   type: 'warning',
        //   message: 'Error occured.\r\n' + error,
        // });
      });

      child.stdout.setEncoding('utf8');
      child.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      });

      child.stderr.setEncoding('utf8');
      child.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        mainWindow.webContents.send('mainprocess-response', data);

        console.log(data);
      });

      if (typeof callback === 'function') callback();
    }
    run_script('start <path to photoshop.exe>', ['<path to image u want to edit']);
```